# How to resolve this "Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted"?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

,oI have included in my flutter page a simple GoogleMap component only to see if it works but I can't fix this issue. I'm compiling the application and when I navigate to the page I'm getting the following error in the console:

> "E/GoogleMapController( 3376): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted"

I can see the component but I'm not able to see the map (see the image attached):

![googleMap example flutter] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJEXE.png)

Added configurations:

```
//(AndroidManifest.xml)

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="apikey"/>

//(pubspec.yaml)
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.0
```

**UPDATE: Solution from 2019**

Added the permission package to request permission. You can install this package to manage your permissions: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission

**UPDATE: 14/06/2023**

This solution could be deprecated since the last version of the package was published on 2020. Also, looking at the package version it can be unstable (0.1.7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is considered a dangerous permission. Have you used the `permission` package to request the permission? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission

Comment: Yes, I know. It was only to check if it resolves my problem. No, I will add the permission package!

Comment: I used the permission package as suggested. @JuthiSarkerAka

Answer (score 7):

As of **December 2019**  I was not successful with using the [permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission) plugin. Even after adding the necessary manifest data and upgrading the project to `Android API 29` it still returned, `PermissionStatus.notAgain`.

What did work was adding the [permissions_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-) plugin with the [manifest data](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) they provided (just the location part). Also, upgrading the Android API to 29 as detailed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608#issuecomment-548649907) and changing the `compileSDKVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `android/app/build.gradle` to `29`.

Mainfest data, just before the `<application>` tag in directory `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- Permissions options for the `location` group -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Restart the IDE to make sure all those changes take effect. Then to request the permission in your app:

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void setPermissions() async{
   Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = 
   await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

May be your API key is not setup properly and granted location service access.

Check and enable these services

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If on an emulator delete the following in your **AndroidManifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and keep:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This worked for me.  I also closed out and rebuilt the entire app in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue:

1. Enabling Map SDK on the Google Console.
2. Stop the project running and run **flutter clean** command.
3. Uninstall the app from device and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Include this if statement in your main function before running the Stateless/Stateful widget in runApp().

```
void main() {
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
  }
runApp(LocationPage());
}
```

If you encounter anymore problems, check the log for links to assist in setting up your project with Google Maps SDK.
The step-by-step procedures are easy to follow and understand.
Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this in an emilator by:

1. #1 Go to the device settings
2. Search for location
3. Chose Location manger
4. Look for my app in the list and click on it
5. Then chose a permission.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of **November 2023**, this is what worked for me:

- make sure that all necessary permissions are available in the manifest file.
- uninstall the app
- reinstall it
- go to the app setting (app info which you get by long pressing the app icon)
- finally, grant it location permission from there.

That is it.

Answer (score -1):

**after adding to AndroidManifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**for platform Android 11 and above, check and enable location permission as follow:**

```
  //ask for location permission
  await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
```