# Flutter Google maps not loading because of asynchronous suspension

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am building an app in Flutter. I tried incorporating google maps into the app, but I can't see map on the emulator, as well as real device. I can see the google logo down on the screen and also zoom options can be seen. I have enabled maps sdk for android in google console. Also, I have added  meta data required before activity tag.

My dart file displaying maps:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static const LatLng _kMapCenter =
      LatLng(19.018255973653343, 72.84793849278007);

  static const CameraPosition _kInitialPosition =
      CameraPosition(target: _kMapCenter, zoom: 11.0, tilt: 0, bearing: 0);

  late GoogleMapController _controller;

  Future onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    _controller = controller;
    String value = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/map_style.json');
    _controller.setMapStyle(value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Maps Demo'),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition,
        onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My debug console:

```
Restarted application in 1,719ms.
E/Surface (14290): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe81e0710
I/AssistStructure(14290): Flattened final assist data: 376 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
D/MapsInitializer(14290): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzcb    (14290): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API(14290): Google Play services package version: 224617040
I/Google Maps Android API(14290): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
I/PlatformViewsController(14290): Using hybrid composition for platform view: 0
E/GoogleMapController(14290): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
E/EGL_emulation(14290): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation(14290): tid 14290: eglQueryContext(2019): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
D/HostConnection(14290): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb73d0620, tid 14683
D/HostConnection(14290): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
D/EGL_emulation(14290): eglCreateContext: 0xa9c85870: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
2
D/EGL_emulation(14290): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9c85870: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xa8476730) (first time)
E/flutter (14290): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/map_style.json
E/flutter (14290): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:258
E/flutter (14290): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14290): #1      AssetBundle.loadString
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:83
E/flutter (14290): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14290): #2      _HomeState.onMapCreated
package:d4u/…/withcar/home.dart:22
E/flutter (14290): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14290):
I/com.example.d4(14290): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 18209(1181KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4065KB/8131KB, paused 3.627ms total 110.580ms
F/crash_dump32(14756): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 161: Permission denied
I/com.example.d4(14290): Thread[3,tid=14299,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xda884610,peer=0x132c0228,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/com.example.d4(14290):
I/com.example.d4(14290): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2
E/libprocessgroup(14290): set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
F/crash_dump32(14917): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 161: Permission denied
E/libprocessgroup(14290): set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

[Screenshot of screen displaying maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQlg7.png)

I had problem with google maps showing grey screen at first, and I found out that it was because of the emulator doesn't support google maps. But in other emulator also, I can't see maps. I have attached the image of my screen. I also tried in real android device, but it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this post will help you : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500970/how-to-resolve-this-cannot-enable-mylocation-layer-as-location-permissions-are)

Here I provided a sample code which actually works on both my emulator and device

```
class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  const Map({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Map> createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(13.660397, 100.525939),
    zoom: 4,
  );
  late GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  Marker? _origin;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _googleMapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
        onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
        markers: {
          if (_origin != null) _origin!,
        },
        onTap: _addMarker,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_initialCameraPosition),
        ),
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: const Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```